# Reordenar un array primitivo (desplazamiento)

Tags: java, java-8, codificación

En base a una codificación de seguridad necesito realizar un desplazamiento en un array para usarlo como base para un cifrado cesar

de modo que si el array inicial es {0,1,2,3} en caso de realizar un desplazamiento de orden 2 mi nuevo array seria {2,3,0,1}

De momento estoy declarando mi array como un int arr[]

¿Cómo puedo hacer esta reordenación de array sin meterme en algo muy loco?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 void desplazar( int arrAlg[], int desplazamiento ) {
      int largo = arrAlg.length;
      int salida[] = new int[ largo ];
      for( int i = 0; i < largo; i++ ) {
          salida[ desplazamiento ] = arrAlg[ i ];
          desplazamiento++;
          if( desplazamiento == largo ) {
             desplazamiento = 0;
          }         
      }      
      return salida;
  }
```

Esta es otra forma de lograr lo que necesitas.
Creamos la variable **largo**, para que sea más eficiente (no le pedimos **`n`** veces el largo al `array`), y el `array` que devolveremos.
Dentro del `for`, inicializas los valores de la variable **salida**, partiendo de la posición que coincide con el desplazamiento, luego aumentamos **desplazamiento**, y verificamos si esta es igual al largo del `array`, en cuyo caso la seteamos en "`0`", solo nos resta devolver el `array`.

Ahora bien, si necesitas que devuelva una cadena (como parece indicar tu propia respuesta), necesitamos hacer unas ligeras modificaciones.
Primero reemplazamos el `array` de salida, por una cadena.
En la anterior, recorrimos el `array` desde su posición "`0`", en esta, empezamos en la posición **largo - desplazar**, que nos coloca sobre el número que debe ocupar la primera posición, lo demás es idéntico.

```
void desplazar( int arrAlg[], int desplazar ) {
   int largo = arrAlg.length;
   String salida = "";
   int desplazamiento = largo - desplazar;
   for( int i = 0; i < largo; i++ ) {
      salida += arrAlg[ desplazamiento ];
      desplazamiento++;
      if( desplazamiento == largo ) {
          desplazamiento = 0;
      }         
   }
   return salida;      
}
```

Comment: Pues efectivamente, es mucho mas limpio y fácil de mantener. Muchas gracias por el esfuerzo, adaptare mi lógica. Un saludo

Comment: Un placer ayudarte!!, saludos!!

Answer (score 1):

De forma tentativa he generado este bloque de código que hace el trabajo aunque no se si es la forma mas eficiente de hacerlo:

```
    int arrAlg[] = Constants.arr;
    int claveSuma = obtenerClaveSuma();
    int claveDesp = claveSuma % 10; //La clave de desplazamiento
    int j = 0;      //El index en el que estoy insertando
    int pos = 0;    //Si recupero del array desde la zona inicial 
    StringBuilder posi = new StringBuilder();
    while( j < 10) { //Mi Key es de 10
       if (claveDesp < 10) { //Si la claveDesp es 10, es que ya estoy fuera del array
           posi.append(arrAlg[claveDesp]);
           claveDesp++;
       } else {
           posi.append(arrAlg[pos]); //Si no voy por clave desplazamiento concateno 
                                     // la parte inicial del array al final de la misma
           pos++;
       }
       j++;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```java
public class CesarCipher {
    public static String encrypt(String message, int key) {
        StringBuilder encryptedMessage = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < message.length(); i++) {
            char ch = message.charAt(i);
            if (Character.isLetterOrDigit(ch)) {
                char encryptedChar;
                if (Character.isLetter(ch)) {
                    // Encripta letras
                    encryptedChar = encryptLetter(ch, key);
                } else {
                    // Encripta números
                    encryptedChar = encryptNumber(ch, key);
                }
                encryptedMessage.append(encryptedChar);
            } else {
                // Conserva los caracteres que no son letras ni números sin encriptar
                encryptedMessage.append(ch);
            }
        }
        return encryptedMessage.toString();
    }

    private static char encryptLetter(char ch, int key) {
        int offset = Character.isUpperCase(ch) ? 'A' : 'a';
        return (char) (((ch - offset + key) % 26) + offset);
    }

    private static char encryptNumber(char ch, int key) {
        int offset = '0';
        return (char) (((ch - offset + key) % 10) + offset);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String message = "Hello123";
        int key = 3;

        String encryptedMessage = encrypt(message, key);
        System.out.println("Mensaje encriptado: " + encryptedMessage);
    }
}
```

[ITM-Developers](https://www.facebook.com/ITMDevelopers)

https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask